# c3JS Load Function

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

1. I'm making c3js chart that looks like:

   ```
   var chart = c3.generate({
       bindto: '#chart',
       data: {
       columns: []
       }
   });
   ```
2. Then I'm trying to use load function from it's api:

   ```
   var data =  [["Name", "15", "30", "45"], ["x", "1", "2", "3"]];

   function update_graph(arg) {
   var tmp = arg[0][1];
   chart.load({
       xs: {
           tmp : arg[1][0]  //binding data to x here and getting an error
       },
       columns: [
           arg[0],
           arg[1]
       ],
   });
   }
   update_graph(data);
   ```

And I'm getting: Uncaught Error: x is not defined for id = "Name".
If I set in xs section: Name : arg[1][0] - it does work. But then I will not be able to draw different lines from different arrays with this function. What am I doing wrong ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working code to make setting key/value to be generic from 'arg' 2D array:- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/93s7204m/)

Solution is to construct the xs object first like:-

```
var xs = {};
xs[arg[0][0]] = arg[1][0];
xs[arg[2][0]] = arg[3][0];
```

and then use xs object in the chart.load function like:-

```
chart.load({
  xs: xs,
  columns: [
    arg[0],
    arg[1],
    arg[2],
    arg[3],
  ],
});
```

Note that key in xs object is not hardcoded to 'Name' or 'Age' string. 
Hope this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Following example is working fine, with multiple lines defined in different arrays.- [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chetanbh/93s7204m/)

```
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
data: {
   columns: []
}
});


var data =  [["Name", "15", "30", "45"], ["x", "1", "2", "3"], ["Age", "45", "38", "25"], ["y", "1", "2", "4"]];

function update_graph(arg) {
  var tmp = arg[0][1];
  chart.load({
   xs: {
    Name : arg[1][0],
    Age : arg[3][0]  //binding data to x here and getting an error
   },
   columns: [
     arg[0],
     arg[1],
     arg[2],
     arg[3],
   ],
 });
}
update_graph(data);
```

Not sure what the issue is, which version of c3js library are you using?
Please refer to the c3js example:- [c3js Example](http://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy_multiple.html)

Comment: I'm using their latest version: "0.4.8". It is working when I know that my columns will always have names such as 'Name' or 'Age'. But when I receive var data with an 'unknown' column and all that I have to do is to take data[0][0] - 1st element. And I can't do xs: {data[0][0] : arg[1][0]} nor {tmp : arg[1][0]}. In 1st case it says about unexpected '[' and in the 2nd case it says about 'x is not defined for id'.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $scope.barchart = function(data,id,chtype,keydata)
    {      
       var xs1 = {};
        var key1 = $scope.obj.key;
        var data1 = $scope.obj.data;
        xs1[key1] = data1;

       var id = c3.generate({
        bindto : '#'+id,
        data: {
            xs:xs1,
            columns: data,
            type: 'scatter',
        },
      }); 


    }
```

Comment: Please try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Thanks